# CarouselView not showing content when its added from the ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a `CarouselView` that only displays an Image, the `CarouselView` is Bound to a list of a Model that only stores one String.

Now when I add an image to that list from the constructor in the ViewModel it works as expected, but I have a method that runs `OnAppearing` and I want it to be set from there.

Now when I add an image to that list from that Method, it adds the image to the list but it does not display it in the `CarouselView`.

Has anybody an idea why this happens?

My code:
View:

```
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}"
                                  HeightRequest="260"
                                  Loop="False"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CarouselImage">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                           HeightRequest="260"
                                           Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CarouselView>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace YourPartys.ViewModels
{
   [QueryProperty(nameof(Locationid), nameof(Locationid))]
   public class DetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
       #region Variables

       #endregion

       #region Propertys
       public List<CarouselImage> ImageList { get; set; } = new List<CarouselImage>();
       string locationid;
       public string Locationid
       {
           get => locationid;
           set => SetProperty(ref locationid, value);
       }
       LocationModel location;
       public LocationModel Location
       {
           get => location;
           set => SetProperty(ref location, value);
       }
       #endregion


       //Constructor
       public DetailViewModel()
       {
           Location = new LocationModel();

           //ImageList.Add(new CarouselImage { Image = "https://club-l1.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/dsc08645-1200x800.jpg" });
       }

       public override async void VModelActive(Page sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
       {
           base.VModelActive(sender, eventArgs);

           Location = await FirestoreService.GetOneLocation(Collection: "Locations", Locationid: Locationid);

           //List for images
           if (Location != null)
           {
               if (Location.Images.MainImage != null)
               { ImageList.Add(new CarouselImage() { Image = Location.Images.MainImage }); };
               foreach (string _image in Location.Images.ExtraImages)
               {
                   ImageList.Add(new CarouselImage() { Image = _image });
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: I also have a CollectionView and it has the same issue where it dose not display the content when it's set from OnAppearing.

Comment: you need to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` if you want the UI to update dynamically

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection` instead of `List` Works